# Scope that returns parent records where all associated records have a file attached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, scope

Suppose there's a `User` and `Document` records. A `User` `has_many :documents` and a `Document` `belongs_to` a `User`.

A `Document` record `has_one_attached :file` .

I already have two `Document` scopes that will return records with and without an attached file:

*Document.rb*

```
  scope :without_attached_file, -> { where.missing(:file_blob) }
  scope :with_attached_file, -> { where.associated(:file_blob) }
```

How can I write a scope for the `User` model that will return all `User` records for which all associated `Document` records have had a `file` attached?

Example: If a `User` has 10 associated `Document` records and all 10 have an attached `file`, then the scope should include that `User` record.

I believe I should first `count` the amount of associated `Document` records and then compare that number to what the `user.documents.with_attached_file.count` returns, but I can't wrap my head around it.

I've come up with somethin like:

```
   scope :with_attached_files_for_all_documents, -> {
    joins(documents: :file_attachment)
      .group('users.id')
      .having("COUNT(documents.id) = COUNT(CASE WHEN active_storage_attachments.record_type = 'Document' THEN documents.id ELSE NULL END)")
  }
```

But that just returns the count of documents that have an attached file for each given `User` record.

Are there any query patterns useful for this?

Comment: Would it make sense to start searching/asking on https://dba.stackexchange.com/? Turning a SQL query into Rails-speak shouldn't be too hard

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can do this in a single query, but I'm thinking of this as a set difference between users that have any documents, and users that have any documents missing files. I would do this with 3 queries:

- A: Query for all users with a document
- B: Query for all users with a document missing a file
- C: Query for the set difference between A and B using them as subqueries

Then you can build your scope like this:

```rb
  scope :with_attached_files_for_all_documents, -> {
    users_with_files = Document.with_attached_files.select(:user_id)
    users_missing_files = Document.without_attached_files.select(:user_id)
    where(id: users_with_files).where.not(id: users_missing_files)
  }
```

Logically, this is three queries, but transactionally it's only one. The first two are not executed until they are passed into the third, where they are executed as subqueries inside your database.